# Leaflet: Hide polyline behind transparent part of a marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet, transparent, marker, polyline

I am working on an app for pilots to plan their track. I would like to have this kind of marker as a turning point.

[image: Marker icon]

These markers should be connected by a polyline. 
I would like to hide the polyline behind the marker so that it doesn't cover the map. It should not be visible inside:
[image]

Left: Wrong, Right: Correct

Is there any simple way to do it? I can use CircleMarker I guess? But how to end  polyline. Would [MultiOptionsPolyline](https://github.com/hgoebl/Leaflet.MultiOptionsPolyline) help?

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing if there is a better way supported directly by Leaflet, but I don't think it is possible without writing your own renderer. You could do this with canvas by converting the lat/lng to the pixel point, then starting/ending the line an appropriate number of pixels away (based on the radius of the circle). Of course, the simplest option is for the circle not to be transparent in the middle, and drawing it over the line, but that doesn't seem to be what you're looking for.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593925/leaflet-geojson-is-is-possible-to-crop-a-line-feature-before-it-reaches-its-dest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leaflet GeoJSON is is possible to crop a line feature before it reaches its destination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593925/leaflet-geojson-is-is-possible-to-crop-a-line-feature-before-it-reaches-its-dest)

Comment: Thansk for the links, will try!