# Add offset/margin in Leaflet Polyline

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, leaflet.draw

I'm using LeafletJS to make 2 circles and I want to draw a line between them, but when I do that I end up with part of it inside the circle. Is there a way to add a margin or an offset to the line so that it touches the edge of the circle?

My system will ask the user for 2 points and then I will draw programmatically 2 circles and 1 polyline.

[image: Leaflet Circle and Polyline]

```js
const LAT1 = 0, LNG1 = 0;
const LAT2 = 0, LNG2 = 0;

const circle1 = Leaflet.circle([LAT1, LNG1], { radius: 15, color: 'blue', fillOpacity: 0.2 });
const circle2 = Leaflet.circle([LAT2, LNG2], { radius: 15, color: 'blue', fillOpacity: 0.2 });

const polyline = Leaflet.polyline([[LAT1, LNG1], [LAT2, LNG2]], { color: 'red' });
```

Comment: There are probably much more elegant ways, but first thing that comes to mind is to calculate the intersection between the circles and the line, draw a new line between these points and remove the original line.

Comment: If you were using Circle Markers, you could have used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46593925/leaflet-geojson-is-is-possible-to-crop-a-line-feature-before-it-reaches-its-dest/46605542?r=SearchResults#46605542 For Circles, you could either adapt that answer based on zoom, or adjust your Polyline coordinates.